# Laravel PHP - Custom JSON object from DB to PHP to JS to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have to create a [**custom json**](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/02726e5ce9ae5f9b3811) object (I need to decide what info goes where in what order) with data I get from PHP in my Controller.

---

*As I see it, I think I need some roundtrips like this:*

1. Get data from Laravel-form in my Controller (`Input::get('name')`)
2. Pass that data to JavaScript to build my JSON
3. Pass that JSON back to PHP
4. Convert this JSON to a string (to store it in Redis)

*And when I try to read this data go the other way around:*

1. Get data from DB
2. Pass data to JavaScript to get each element/node
3. Parse those values to html (to display the data from the json)

---

**How would I pass variables from PHP to JS and back? Not sure how that works... A good explanation (with some code or example) would be much appreciated!!!**

**Or is there another 'better' way?**

I am using Laravel 5.2 and NoSQL Redis. I need to create a *somewhat* *complex* JSON that looks like [**this**](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/02726e5ce9ae5f9b3811) and store that in Redis. This JSON will never be more than twice the size of this one shown here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to generate json data, you can do that with json_encode function in php. No need to pass to javascript to build json data.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

update:

you can store the response of json_encode function in a variable and you can do whatever you want with that variable

```
$json_data=json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.. But now I have this huge (150+ lines) block of json inmy Controller. s there a way to set this is a seperate file and call it in the Controller (to clear up my Controller clutter)?

Comment: Yes I see you point. But since I build my own JSON structure (not imported from sql table) I have this json variable in my Controlller. Can you make a variable that is useable across the whole project?

Comment: could you paste your controller code ? You can declare global variable so that it is accessible across the whole project

Comment: Not sure if it will be managable, since I will need to pass about 20 variables to that global variable.. Now I have only done it on line 98. https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/e972147b43f8bd03c0b6

Comment: I see you have hard coded a json object to php string variable. It would be better to create an array which holds your key value pairs. Then use json_encode($arrayVariable) to convert array to json.

Comment: Yes, thought this would be faster/easier then array conversion to json. Will try it if I have time though...